# Regex, look for Uppercase code but don't include numbers that start with dollar signs

Tags: regex

I have strings that look similar to this...

If you want to shop in store, use this coupon ZXXZX123 to save $20 off your in-store purchase of $100 or more, or $100 off $500 or more."

In the end all i want is `ZXXZX123`

I have started off with this that looks for Uppercase and numbers and must be at least 2 characters.  After that, I am not sure how to not include the others.  I guess other phrases my include things like 20% off so I don't want to include those types of numbers either.

```
[A-Z0-9]{2,}
```

Comment: Can't you be more precise about the format of a coupon code? Does it always start with a letter or can it start with a digit? Can it be only letters? Can it be only digits? Can it be 20 characters long? The more specific you can be, the better the regex can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lookarounds to ensure you match a whole word (string between spaces):

```
(?<=\s|^)[A-Z0-9]{2,}(?=\s|$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tGJiBb/2)

Explanation:

- `(?<=\s|^)` is positive lookbehind, it ensures that there is a whitespace before the next character that is matched or that this is beginning of the string
- `(?<=\s|$)` is positive lookahead, it ensures that there is a after before the previous character that is matched this is end of the string

Comment: `ZXXZX123 is the coupon code and this example won't work. As Coupon code has to be between two words.`  As you making boundary that word there will be space around the coupon code. So for the string I wrote above, it won't work.

Comment: Thanks, fixed that

Comment: Positive look behind, in the beginning, is not a good idea as it will miss one more scenario. Just in case, example.https://regex101.com/r/XU3AID/5. Do not take it personally just a thought.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. This text is not well formatted though - there should be a space after a dot.

Comment: Thank you all for your submissions.  I have tried them all and they have all seem to be working for what I need.  mrzasa had the first reply and I am currently using it and it's working really well. I guess with regex there is no definitive way of accomplishing a task.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this regex, this will only capture coupon codes.

**Regex:** `'[A-Z][A-Z0-9]+'`

**Explanation:**
`[A-Z]`: First letter is alphabet and is UPPERCASE.
`[A-Z0-9]+`: From second letter and onwards it will look for a combination of digits 0-9 or/and alphabet which is in UPPERCASE.

**Link to Example:** https://regex101.com/r/XU3AID/1

*Let me know if you have any question.*

Comment: This will also capture 'What' and 'OK'.

Comment: Now you have a different problem. It does not capture all of "XY02AB".

Comment: @tricot: With all due respect, and without any assumption, use the link I gave as an example. If it fails then please let me know. It should not and it will not with the two examples you gave me.

Comment: The regex in https://regex101.com/r/XU3AID/1 and  https://regex101.com/r/XU3AID/2 are different. My first comment was about the first -- where "What" is indeed rejected (my mistake), but OK is not (demo: https://regex101.com/r/XU3AID/4), then you posted the second, and my second comment is about that (demo: https://regex101.com/r/XU3AID/3).

Comment: 1. Data in a sentence with CamelCase. Means starts with the first word in a sentence starts with Capital rest except coupon code is lowercase. So Regex in example 1 works fine as per my understanding. 
2. The second regex I created to show you, even if I remove words it will still work and then you agreed that it was your mistake. Here the assumption is that the coupon code will be UPPERCASE and it will have numbers in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the match expressions for uppercase chars and the digits, then combine with a "not $" in the middle.

[A-Z]+[^\$][0-9]+

Comment: `[^\$]` is not required. The Regex will work without that too. Try it out. As you are putting it at the later position in word.

Answer (score 0):

Simply excluding dollar sign would match other characters like  white spaces for example.  So this is won't work : `[^\\$] [A-Z0-9]{2,}`

Instead match for whitespace preceding the code but exclude it by using the capturing group: 
`[\\s]([A-Z0-9]{2,})` and in your match or replacement reference group number 1. See https://regexr.com/45shq